# SIFT flow if we are using Optical flow for a video

Tags: computer-vision

what is the use of SIFT flow if we are using Optical flow for a video

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: In ROBUST VIDEO OBJECT CO-SEGMENTATION paper optical flow is used for motion estimation where SIFT flow is also for the same purpose then what is the use of Optical flow in that paper.

Comment: Interesting one. I am gonna look at it.